# Cleaning deleted Items

Tags: opengl, glsl

In my application user creates and deletes geometry at runtime.

i store vertex data within memory on the graphics card as managed by a vertex buffer object named VBO.

the user deletes the object  but the application is still running.

```
 void CleanUp()
{
 if (!this->isInited)
 {
    return;
 }
   if (this->m_VAO)
       glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &this->m_VAO);

    if (this->m_VBO)
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &this->m_VBO);

 }
```

Will this release the allocated memory from the graphics card ?

Comment: What types are `m_VAO` and `m_VBO`?
If they are integers, you should pass them directly to the gl functions. And in that case, checking for a zero inside the `if` is not necessary - `glDeleteXXX()` can be called with zero-values which results in a no-op. Also don't forget to reset your `isInited`-variable afterwards.

Comment: @maja they are unsigned integers.

Comment: In that case you should be fine. Also note that you can always call `glGetError` to find out if any of your API calls failed: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetError.xhtml